# A counterexample for which the diagonal matrix of a symmetric matrix is not unique

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Consider the symmetric matrix $ A=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & -1 & 3\\ -1 & 2 & 1 \\ 3 & 1 & 1   \end {matrix}\right]$.

Since it is symmetric, there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ and $D_1$=$\left[\begin{matrix} -\sqrt{6} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{6}   \end {matrix}\right]$ such that$$D_1=P^{-1}AP=P^{t}AP.$$

However, when consider the case when A is congruent to $D_2$, $D_2=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -24   \end {matrix}\right]$, and $Q=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & -7\\ 0 & 1 & -4 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end {matrix}\right]$ we have that $$A=Q^{t}D_2Q.$$

So, $D_1$ doesn't equal to $D_2$.

> > My question is what is the missing point so that this weird thing happened. Thank you!

Comment: $Q$ isn't orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congruency is different from similarity in that the former does not preserve the eigenvalues, but it does preserves the sign of them.

Example:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
you could clearly give a congruence between these matrices.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ivy Glad to help you here!